# If function doesn't work as expected in PYTHON

Tags: python

Here is a part of my code where the problem is.
It doesn't matter what the input is, the script will end
when I enter something.

It should restart when i enter "yes" or "y"
Without the OR it works without problem

```
else:
    if number == rndnum:
        print "Congratulations! You won."
        print "Do you want to replay?"
        answer = raw_input("Type y (yes) or n (no): ")
        dialog = 1
        while dialog == 1:
            if answer == "n" or "no":
                replay = 0
                dialog = 0
            elif answer == "y" or "yes":
                dialog = 0
            else:
                answer = raw_input("Type y (yes) or n (no): ")
        loop = 0 #Will overdo loop var and stop the loop
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if answer == "n" or "no":
```

is interpreted by Python as:

```
if (answer == "n") or ("no"):
```

Which is always true, because the second condition in your `or` clause is always `True` (non-empty strings in Python are *truthy*, which means they evaluate to `True` in a condition):

```
>>> bool("no")
True
```

What you need is one of:

```
if answer in ("n", "no"):

# or 

if answer == "n" or answer == "no":
```

Th same goes for `"yes"`, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the shorter version

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your code like this:

```
if answer == "n" or answer == "no":
    # ...
```

and:

```
elif answer == "y" or answer == "yes":
    # ...
```

`a or b`, where `a` and `b` are strings and not both the empty string, will always evaluate to `True` in a boolean context, demo:

```
>>> '' or 'x'
'x'
>>> 'y' or 'x'
'y'
>>> '' or ''
''
>>> if 'x': print('hi')
... 
hi
>>> if '': print('hi')
... 
>>>
```

The first two expressions will evaluate to `True`.